# State a general law suggested

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Observe that

$3^2+4^2=5^2$

$5^2+12^2=13^2$

$7^2+24^2=25^2$

$9^2+40^2=41^2$

State a general law suggested by these examples, and prove it.

For $ a ^ 2 = b ^ 2 + c ^ 2, and (a, b, c) = 1 $. I was thinking of the early Pythagorean triples

Comment: they have picked only your $a = b+1$

Comment: I think Will means that in $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, all their examples have $c = b+1$. If you move the $b^2$ to the other side, you may notice something (or not).

Comment: @JohnHughes I wrote it that way because her last line begins For  $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$

Comment: D'oh! One of us knows how to read better than the other. :(

Comment: $ a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = c ^ 2 $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the smallest you may see

- $1\cdot 3 + 1 = 4$
- $2\cdot 5 + 2 = 12$
- $3\cdot 7 + 3 = 24$
  ...
- Guess: $(2k+1)^2 + (k(2k+1)+k)^2  = (k(2k+1)+k + 1)^2$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ or simplified
- $(2k+1)^2 + (2k(k+1))^2  = (2k(k+1) + 1)^2$ ... which can be verified by direct calculation

Comment: Can it be $ (2k + 1) ^ 2 + (2k (k + 1)) ^ 2 = (2k (2k + 1) +1) ^ 2 $?

Comment: That is the same when simplifying $k(2k+1)+k = k(2k+2)= 2k(k+1)$. I just wanted to write down the very first guess without simplification to show how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

We need $$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$$

to be perfect square

As $2n+1$ is odd,let  $2n+1=(2m+1)^2$ where $m$ is any integer

$\iff n=2m(m+1)$